# Func-Programming in Java. Method-ref doesn't match the Function apply signature yet successfully runs

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, method-reference

I'm currently reading [Functional Programming in Java by Venkat Subramaniam](https://pragprog.com/book/vsjava8/functional-programming-in-java) and so far its been a great read.

There is a particular example however that is causing me some confusion. In the code example below there is a method called `setFilters(final Function<Color,Color>... filters)`.

This expects a list implementing the Function interface. In the code setFilters is called using method references ... `camera.setFilters(Color::lighter, Color::darker);`.

This is confusing because the Color class does not implement the Function interface and nor does it have a method that matches the `R apply(T t);` signature.

Have I missed something obvious here? Can someone please explain how `Color::darker` etc can be passed into a parameter that expects `Function<Color,Color>`

Here is the full code example:

```
package designing.fpij;

import com.sun.scenario.effect.impl.sw.sse.SSEBlend_SRC_OUTPeer;

import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class Camera {  
  private Function<Color, Color> filter;


  public Color capture(final Color inputColor) {
    final Color processedColor = filter.apply(inputColor);
    return processedColor;
  }

  public void setFilters(final Function<Color, Color>... filters) {
    filter =
            Stream.of(filters).
                    reduce((after, before) -> filter.compose(before)).orElse(color -> color);
  }
  public Camera() {
    setFilters();
  }

  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final Camera camera = new Camera();
    final Consumer<String> printCaptured = (filterInfo) ->
            System.out.println(String.format("with %s: %s", filterInfo, camera.capture(new Color(200, 100, 150))));

    System.out.println("//" + "START:NOFILTER_OUTPUT");
    printCaptured.accept("no filter");
    System.out.println("//" + "END:NOFILTER_OUTPUT");

    System.out.println("//" + "START:BOTH_OUTPUT");
    camera.setFilters(Color::brighter, Color::darker);
    printCaptured.accept("brighter & darker filter");
    System.out.println("//" + "END:BOTH_OUTPUT");

  }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling

```
camera.setFilters(Color::darker);
```

is the equivalent of

```
setFilters(new Function<Color, Color>() {
    @Override
    public Color apply(Color color) {
        return color.darker();
    }
});
```

(if you were using pre-Java-8 anonymous inner classes).  You can see when you add all the boilerplate that Color does not need to be a `FunctionalInterface` or implement `Function` - in the longer form you would be wrapping a call to this method inside a `Function`.

Simplifying this call to a lambda gives

```
setFilters((Function<Color, Color>) color -> color.darker());
```

or even shorter:

```
setFilters(color -> color.darker());
```

which ultimately can be simplified into your method reference:

```
setFilters(Color::darker);
```

Comment: Thanks Trisha. This is a very clear and step by step explanation.

Comment: is there an IDE tool that can convert method-references and lambda's into traditional Java6/7 code?

Comment: Yes, I use IntelliJ IDEA to do this for me - pressing "Alt + Enter" on the method reference gives you the option to expand to a lambda, and from there you can use the same process to expand to an anonymous inner class

Answer (score 0):

Java AWT Color class ([docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html)) has **methods** `brighter()` and `darker()`, thus the call actually passes these functions.